# Wintertime and AC line frosted & dripping water in basement?

Tags: hvac

One line IS insulated in the exposed basement ceiling, so I am supposing this frosted & dripping line is the smaller return line? Have a dehumidifier running but the problem remains. What can I do to stop this, it's dripping all over the run of the pipe across 1/2 of the basement. 
Thank You.

I looked all over the internet and this line isn't the one discussed.

Comment: Are you using the A/C?

Comment: no, it's January. Using the furnace. AC is turned off.

Comment: The smaller copper line is completely frosted up, the one that isn't supposed to be insulated. the lines are all exposed in a ceiling in a unfinished basement. The line with the coolant IS insulated and is NOT the problem. It;s the small copper line that is the heat return?

Comment: What's the fuel source for your furnace, gas? Trying to determine if you have a heat pump.

Comment: Gas, clean filter,unit installed this past summer. Don't believe there is a heat pump. Just a regular energy efficient bryant furnace with whole house AC unit included.

Comment: the larger coolant line is insulated as it should be, the smaller copper line is the one that condenses an drips when it isn't completely frosted up. Been running dehumidifier since September down there as it's an unfinished basement. There are three large heating vents down there so basement is same temp as house. 68 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily turn off the power to the condensing unit to be certain it's not running at times. You should have a breaker for it in your electrical panel, or a local disconnect box mounted near the condenser itself.

If it's a heat pump the insulated line may freeze for short times normally or if the switchover valve is stuck for longer times.

Comment: Please don't use acronyms or abbreviations (or explain them in your answer). DIY.SE is for homeowners and others who don't always know industry-specific terms.

Comment: shut off power to AC, called company who installed it, they think a short in the wiring & that the ac has been coming on. Thank you for answering this. No where on the internet, except here, has this issue come up. THANK YOU!!!!!